# java program ask user to roll dice and i have trouble here

Tags: java

**Question**

The rules of the basic game we covered in class and may be summarized as follows. The first roll of the dice ends in a win or a loss or a requirement to continue to throw the dice. If the first roll is a 7 or 11 it is a win. If the first roll is a 2, 3, or 12 it is a loss. For any other total (the point as it is called) you must rethrow the dice until you either repeat the point or throw a 7. If a rethrow generates a 7 it is a loss. If a rethrow produces the point it is a win. If neither occurs you must continue to rethrow.

```
public class CrapsGame{


public static void main(String[] args) {
```

public class CrapsGame{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

```
int time; //number of times the game user want to play
int rolls=0; //number of rolls
int mypoint=0; 
int d1; //number user rolled for first dice
int d2; //number user rolled for second dice
int total=0; //total number of rolls 
int Numwins=0; //number of wins
int Numlosses = 0; //number of losses
double averolls=0;  //average number of rolls per game
double probwin=0; //probability of win
boolean win, rollagain=false;                  

win = false;
System.out.println("Enter the number of times the game you want to play: ");
time=TextIO.getlnInt();   



 for (int i=0; i<time; i++){
      d1=(int)(6*Math.random())+1; //user roll dice(generate a random number)
      d2=(int)(6*Math.random())+1;      
      rolls =0; 
   switch (d1+d2) {
      case 7: 
      case 11:
        win=true; //when first roll is 7 or 11, player win
        break;
      case 2: 
      case 3: 
      case 12:
        win=false; //when first roll is 2,3 or 12, player lose
        break;
      default:
        mypoint = d1+d2;
        rollagain=true; //when first roll is 1,4,5,6,8,9,10 or 11, player rethrow dice      
   }
        do{
          d1=(int)(6*Math.random())+1;
          d2=(int)(6*Math.random())+1;
           System.out.printf("%d and %d\n",d1,d2);
          rolls++;
          total = total + rolls;
          if (d1+d2 == mypoint ){
            win=true;
            rollagain=false;           
          }
          else if ( d1+d2 == 7){
            win=false;
            rollagain=false;           
          }
        } while(rollagain);


}

if (win){
  System.out.printf("***WINNER***\n");
  Numwins++;}
else {
  System.out.printf("YOU LOSE\n");
 Numlosses++;}


probwin = Numwins / time;
averolls = total / time ;

System.out.printf("Avg # rolls: %.2f\n",averolls);
System.out.printf("Max # rolls: %d\n",rolls);
System.out.printf("# of wins: %d\n",Numwins);
System.out.printf("# of losses: %d\n",Numlosses);
System.out.printf("The probability of a win: %.2f.\n",probwin);




 }

}Thats all i have so far. My questions are
```

1.why the program is not calculating the average of rolls per game, number of wins and number of losses for me?

2.the program need to ask user at the beginning how many games do they want to play. then i decided to use a for loop but it says time cant be resolved to a variable. idk what is going on.

3.after the first roll, if user roll same `enter code here` number as first time, they win the game. but my code is not doing it. idk why. help me ty!

Comment: It is not what you asked, but your random number generation is off. It does not account for 7 being likelier than 12, say. Roll 2 dice and add them.

Comment: average number of rolls should be the total number of rolls divided by the number of times you play.

Comment: What @Jeremy Kahan says points to a reason to break out `int rollDie()` as its own method.

Comment: "time cant be resolved to a variable": you need `int time=TextIO.getlnInt();`  (also `time` is a poor choice for a variable name, IMO)

Comment: i edited it again sirs. it finally runs but all the calculation parts are giving me wrong number. i believe my code is correct but it keeps doing some stupid math. plz help

Comment: add rolls to total outside the do loop

Answer (score 0):

One reason it will not function correctly is that you need to set 'point=d' when you go into the default section. Currently you leave point set to zero but then you compare against it as the target point.

The reason time cannot be resolved is that you have it commented out in your example.

As far as question 1: note that 'total' is never updated. It is always left at 0.

Comment: its still not working after i set point = d in default.   plz help me again

Comment: You need to initialize rollagain to false, so that 7, 11, 2, 3, 12 lead to not rolling again. Also I am pretty sure you want to use a while and not a do...while loop, since in those cases, the loop should not execute even once. You also need a rolls++ after the throw of the dice in the first line inside the for loop. And the denominator of average should be time and the numerator numrolls. @Oscar is correct that total is never getting incremented, and besides it should be the same as time (so superfluous).

Comment: i followed your instructions and change it. still not working. seeking for more help. due on wednesday, i am so panic right now

Comment: Can you update your post to show the current code? I think too much of your updating variables is happening inside the switch default, which means wins and losses are not getting counted if they happen first. Is the goal to report averages and probabilities after every game, or only at the end. You will also need to update what you mean by "not working" if it is no longer your 1 to 3.

Comment: i updated sir. i follow your instruction change it to while loop. its not working. i am first year student, so i am so confused right now. PLZ help me! tytyytytytytytytyty

Comment: report only at the end

Comment: i edited it again sirs. it finally runs but all the calculation parts are giving me wrong number. i believe my code is correct but it keeps doing some stupid math. plz help